# Does rolling back an edit takes rep away from the person who suggested it?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, reputation

I'm just wondering whether the person who suggested an edit would lose 2 reputation if the edit he/she suggested is rolled back.

Why do we give rep to users who suggested an edit that gets approved? Because this is *contribution*, right? The user contributed by improving an answer/question. We give rep to him/her because we want to encourage them to contribute.

So if the edit is rolled back, there is *no* contribution any more, because whoever rolled back that edit thinks the edit is not good. I guess it would make sense to take rep off of the suggester.

Is this true? If it is not, can we implement such a feature?

Comment: What behaviour would that change and why would we want to change it?

Comment: You're not targeting the right issue for me - why was this hypothetical edit (that was so bad it needed to be rolled back) approved in the first place?

Comment: They get a badge. It's called Cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

No such mechanic exists. See [this question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) and its responses. As Tunaki has pointed out, and the top answer there states, bad edits getting approved is just a symptom of a larger problem: edits being reviewed by people who shouldn't even be reviewing in the first place.